# How do halt repeating back slashes?

Tags: php, backslash

My PHP application adds backslashes to quotes in many locations with `addslashes()`. Unfortunately, this adding has produced output akin to the following.

Every time I refresh my page, this string increases in number of back slashes.

don't
don\'t
don\\'t
don\\\\'t
don\\\\\\\\'t

and so on.

I want to write a function that deletes all these extra back slashes. I have tried

```
str_replace($text, "\\\\", "");
```

to no avail.

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful. It could be a magic quotes issue, or how you have your addslashes utilized, or... Code is always the best way to get specific help with your coding question. But I'm leaning on just using stripslashes for your output, or only using addslashes just before a presumed database submission.

Comment: I think the sensible solution is to not call addslashes() at all. Instead, only add slashes manually when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may just use:

```
 stripslashes($text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text=preg_replace('/\134+/',"\134",$text);
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if your actual value happens to include `\\` legitimately? For instance, if your content were referring to a Windows-style share reference - `\\192.168.1.1\foo`. If you blindly strip out any double slashes, you'll strip out ones that are *meant* to be there, as well.

The "right" answer is really to not add slashes to things that don't need them. You should know whether a given value is already escaped or not (after all, you're the one controlling where every value comes from, and what it's being used for) and only add slashes when you need them.